# How to insert a record blob field in SQL to a Paradox table?

Tags: sql, paradox

I am using the SQL editor in Paradox 9. I am trying to insert a record into a table that contains a blob (Binary) field. My SQL statement is as follows:

```
insert into table1.db (field1, field2)  values ('value1', 'value2')
```

That returns the error

> "Type mismatch in expression"

I want to do something like the following:

```
insert into table1.db (field1, field2)  values (str_to_hex('value1'), str_to_hex('value2'))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what's datatype of columns?

Comment: Both fields are Binary